# Single Sign On with Devise and OmniAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, single-sign-on

There is a lot of information about using OmniAuth and Devise to be able to login to a webapp using facebook and twitter.  However, I am trying to write my own OAuth provider and not use fb/twitter etc. (and failing to find examples).

I basically want to have two apps - a UserManager which has a table of users, and WebApp1 (and possible more in the future).  I want a user to be able to go to WebApp1 and be redirected to the UserMAnager to be able to login, and then be redirected back to WebApp1.   I don't want WebApp1 to have a table of users.

Can I have some pointers?   At this stage I believe I need Devise in both apps, and OmniAuth in WebApp1, although I'm not 100% certain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you still have this as a question.

There is a nice writeup that sounds very similar to your use case.

http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2010/12/16/multiple-applications-with-devise-omniauth-and-single-sign-on/

Best of luck