# RubyOnRails kind of Single Sign On strategy for devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, devise, single-sign-on, omniauth

I want approved external site users to have access in my app automaticaly.

So i have trusted external sites, and i want to have their users atomaticaly have a user on my site. So there would be no need to approve anything per user, only per site...

How to do this in Devise? Omniauth?

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at:

https://github.com/nbudin/devise_cas_authenticatable

https://github.com/apokalipto/devise_saml_authenticatable

Or if you don't want to use Devise:

[Casino Single Sign on](http://casino.rbcas.com)

Or take a look at this topic:

[Single Sign On with Devise and OmniAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937634/single-sign-on-with-devise-and-omniauth)